# Equivalent of PreviewKeyDown of C# needed for native C++/MFC

Tags: c#, c++, event-handling

I used a `ActiveXControl` in a C# Forms application and had the possibility to implement a `PreviewKeyDown` event handler for that `ActiveXControl`. That was needed to specify that, e.g. the [ALT] key, is an input key.

For some reasons or other I have to reimplement the application in native C++/MFC and don't know how to specify that this [ALT] key is an input key and to be handled by the `ActiveXControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the `GetAsyncKeyState` Win32 function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the state of all the keys in the system, `VK_MENU` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the key you should monitor for the **[Alt]** key.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but MSDN doesn't say that you won't get a `WM_KEYDOWN` for the ALT key -- any other key pressed while ALT is down generates a `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, but that doesn't say that you can't handle ALT via `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SetTimer to generate a WM_TIMER event 20 times a second or so

```
SetTimer( NULL, kMyTimer, 50, MyTimerCallback );
```

Then implement a function as follows.

```
 void CALLBACK MyTimerCallback( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime )
 {
      static short lastLeftAltPress = 0;
      short thisLeftAltPress = GetAsyncKeyState( VK_LMENU );
      if ( thisLeftAltPress != 0 && lastLeftAltPress == 0 )
      {
           CallAltHandlingCode();
      }
      thisLeftAltPress = lastLestAltPress;

      // Handling code for other keys goes here.
 }
```

This will then poll the keyboard every 50ms to find out if the left alt key has just been pressed and then call your handling code.  If you want to fire the handler when its released then you would use the following if statement

```
 if ( thisLeftAltPress == 0 && lastLeftAltPress != 0 )
```

or if you just want to see if it is down then you do

```
 if ( thisLeftAltPress != 0 )
```

The docs for [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx) do state that you can check whether the lowest bit is set to see if the key has just been pressed but it does also point out that this may fail in unexpected ways in multi-threaded environments.  The above scheme should always work.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your recommendations.

For my case I finally found some way how to make it work. So far what I have learnt the situation is that a PreviewKeyDown event is triggered before the KeyDown message is sent.

I implemented PreTranslateMessage in the dialog which hosts the ActiveX control and called ::SendMessage(WM_KEYDOWN...) with the handle of the ActiveX control, using pMsg for the arguments.

Cheers,

Ilmari